# Time series: how to model the impact of exogenous variable?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, modeling

Disclaimer: this is a more theoretical question than a practical one.

I am trying to predict the revenues of a company (so I can't post the data) using the past 4 years data (monthly) and exogenous variables such as specific discount events that happen during the year.
These events are not always in the same months, so in the future the user would need to inform the model when they will happen.

Concerning the past, the only information I have about these events is their presence or absence. However, I would like to add an extra dimension / nuance because different events can be present at the same time but I know that some will have a bigger financial impact than others.

In other words, I have three events: A, B, C.
Each event will fed the model as 0 if the event is absent during that month, or 1 if it is present. With this I can explain to the model why we have some picks - because those events were happening during those months. However I miss the impact dimension: I know that event B is bigger than A and C. Is there a smart way to model this?

I am new in time series so please don't take any info for granted!

Comment: The impact will be estimated by whatever procedure you use to estimate your model, so you don't need to worry about folding it into your independent variable - a 0 or 1 will do.  You would have one 0-1 variable for each of the three events, and you will get an estimate of the impact of each event on revenue.